# Command not found when SSHing into server via non-interactive session

Tags: github-actions, ubuntu-20.04

I'm using a GitHub action to SSH into my staging server to pull the latest from the repo (which succeeds) then install node modules: `yarn` (which fails), build the app: `yarn build:app` (which fails), then restart the app: `pm2 restart all` (which fails). From what I've read from researching, the commands aren't found because the SSH into the server is a non-interactive session and many things aren't added to $PATH. I have tried adding `export PATH="$PATH:/home/***/.nvm/versions/node/v14.5.0/bin/pm2:/home/***/.nvm/versions/node/v14.5.0/bin/pm2"` to my script to no avail. I'm still getting command not found.

```
name: Test Deployment

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - staging

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Deploy Staging
        if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/staging'
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
        with:
          host: ${{ secrets.STAGING_SSH_HOST }}
          username: ${{ secrets.STAGING_SSH_USERNAME }}
          key: ${{ secrets.STAGING_SSH_KEY }}
          passphrase: ${{ secrets.STAGING_SSH_PASSPHRASE }}
          port: ${{ secrets.STAGING_SSH_PORT }}
          script: |
            export PATH="$PATH:/home/***/.nvm/versions/node/v14.5.0/bin/pm2:/home/***/.nvm/versions/node/v14.5.0/bin/pm2"
            cd ~/***
            git pull origin staging
            yarn
            yarn build:app
            pm2 restart all
```

Receiving errors:

```
======CMD======
export PATH="$PATH:/home/***/.nvm/versions/node/v14.5.0/bin/pm2:/home/***/.nvm/versions/node/v14.5.0/bin/pm2"
cd ~/***
git pull origin staging
yarn
yarn build:app
pm2 restart all

======END======
err: From github.com:***/***
err:  * branch            staging    -> FETCH_HEAD
err:  ***  staging    -> origin/staging
out: Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
2021/04/16 21:28:17 Process exited with status 127
out:  .github/workflows/main.yml | 2 +-
out:  1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
err: bash: line 3: yarn: command not found
err: bash: line 4: yarn: command not found
err: bash: line 5: pm2: command not found
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
export path='$PATH:/home/***/.nvm/versions/node/v14.5.0/bin/pm2:/home/***/.nvm/versions/node/v14.5.0/bin/pm2'
```

you should try

```
export PATH="$PATH:/home/***/.nvm/versions/node/v14.5.0/bin/pm2:/home/***/.nvm/versions/node/v14.5.0/bin/pm2"
```

Notice:

1. PATH - uppercase
2. Use double quote instead of single quote to expand the previous value of PATH variable

Comment: I'm getting the same error. Updated question with this edit as well as the output / error that unfortunately still remains.

Comment: @DavidS: Is the path /home/***/.nvm/versions/node/v14.5.0/bin/pm2 correct? What is the pm2 at the end, a folder or a file?

Comment: File! Silly me. Using ```export PATH="$PATH:/home/***/.nvm/versions/node/v14.5.0/bin/"``` works. Thank you so much. Stupid oversights.