# How to deploy it in Nestjs (EC2) via Github Actions

Tags: github-actions

I want to automatically distribute it through GitHub Action.

So I have `CI` as shown below.

```js
name: CICD

on:
  push:
    branches: ['dev']

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Use Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: '16'
      - name: Install and build
        run: |
          yarn install
          yarn build


  deploy:
    needs: [build]
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: SSH and Deploy
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
        with:
          host: ${{ secrets.REMOTE_IP }}
          username: ${{ secrets.REMOTE_SSH_ID }}
          key: ${{ secrets.REMOTE_SSH_KEY }}
          port: ${{ secrets.REMOTE_SSH_PORT }}
          command_timeout: 20m
          script: |
            cd /home/ubuntu/api/favi2-api
            git pull origin dev
            pm2 reload my_app
```

But this is not reflected on the server.
I think it's because there's no content of the BUILD `Dist` folder from the server.

Should I delete this item /DIST item to .gitignore?
But this seems to be too big problems.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `yarn build` is done on the GitHub Action runner, not on your target deployment server.

That is why one option would be to trigger the build on that server, as you can [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67132301/6309)

```yaml
jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Deploy Staging
        if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/staging'
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
        with:
          host: ${{ secrets.STAGING_SSH_HOST }}
          username: ${{ secrets.STAGING_SSH_USERNAME }}
          key: ${{ secrets.STAGING_SSH_KEY }}
          passphrase: ${{ secrets.STAGING_SSH_PASSPHRASE }}
          port: ${{ secrets.STAGING_SSH_PORT }}
          script: |
            xport PATH="$PATH:/home/***/.nvm/versions/node/v14.5.0/bin/pm2:/home/***/.nvm/versions/node/v14.5.0/bin/pm2"
            cd ~/***
            git pull origin staging
            yarn
            yarn build:app
            pm2 restart all
```

The drawback is your "production" server now must have build tools installed in it.

---

> I was looking for a way to do it on GitHub because build on the server would cause too much load. Is my concept wrong?

Your concept is *not* wrong at all: it is a best practice, for a production server, to limit itself to *run* an application, not to build one.

Ideally, if said server had Docker, you could build an image from GitHub, and pull that image to run it.

Otherwise, you need to zip what you are building, `scp` it to the server, which will unzip it to the target folder.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I was looking for a way to do it on GitHub because build on the server would cause too much load.
Is my concept wrong?